# Does MATLAB java.util have non-hash map/set?

Tags: java, matlab

`java.util.Map/Set` are abstract. We have `java.util.HashMap/HashSet/HashTable`. Do we have any `Map/Set` with sorted keys in `java.util`?

Comment: You can use any java collection in Matlab. If your question is not about Matlab, but java in general, please make it clear.

Comment: @nirvana-msu My question is about MATLAB. I did not realize that we can call any Java collections...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, `TreeSet`, `TreeMap`.

Documentation is really part of Java. E.G., you can start here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Some examples:

```
>> x = java.util.TreeSet;
>> x.add(2);
>> x.add(1);
>> x.add(3);
>> x
x =
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]

>> y = java.util.TreeMap;
>> y.put(10, 'ten');
>> y.put(20, 'twenty');
>> y.put(1, 'one');
>> y
y =
{1.0=one, 10.0=ten, 20.0=twenty}
```

To see a list of all available Java classes, it's easiest to use the Javadocs web site, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

As noted in the comments, calling Java classes from Matlab is not particularly fast. I believe Matlab uses the Java reflection construct to allow execution of ad hoc, uncompiled Java code ... not fast. Sometimes still useful.

Comment: Is there a way we can list all classes under java.util? tab does not work for this package.

Comment: FYI, the speed of using Java containers in MATLAB is incredibly slow compared to how fast java.util methods are in a pure java setting: MATLAB just adds too much overhead. Eg. adding 1 million random MATLAB strings to a java.util.Hashmap take over 50 seconds on my machine, but do a similar operation entirely in Java and it takes only about 2 seconds.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Will java.util.TreeMap be faster than MATLAB's containers.Map? Would implementing a C++ std container wrapper by mex the fast way? Although I do not know if anyone already made this.

Comment: @Pursuit Would https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html be a better link? I assume MATLAB java.util works for the java package java.util, does not it?

Comment: @JoeC In my experience, containers.Map was faster, but I could easily see this varying between version of MATLAB. Wrapping a c++ std container with MEX and doing as much of your stuff batched together in a single call to a mex function would be the fastest (a hacky thing to do is return the pointer to std::map as a uint64 back to matlab so you can use in subsequent calls), but that's also an error prone, giant pain in the rear. I'd just keep it simple and use a containers.map or java.util stuff unless it's a huge problem.

Comment: @JoeC. You can use the entire Java library, not just stuff from java.util. For example, there are times when `java.math.BigDecimal` is a convenient tool to have available.  (FWIW, I agree with Mathew Gunn on expected speeds)

Comment: Why is MATLAB's map slower than c++? Is it because it works as an interpreter but not compiled? Are there any other overhead comparing to c++？